# Latex parentheses in R plot

Tags: r, plot, latex

I am using `latex2exp` package to add math expression in a plot with R. I have an error when I use `\\\left(` to resize a parenthesis to encompass a fraction.
Can someone can help ? Thanks.

```
ttt <- TeX("$(\\\left(\\\frac{M}{L} = 0.08$")
```

I have the following error message when I use `\\\\left(`

> Original string:  $\left( \frac{M}{L} = 0.08$
>   Parsed expression:  paste('','',bgroup('(', paste('','',frac(paste('M'), paste('','L')),'',phantom() == phantom(),'0','.','08','') )
>   Error in parse(text = str) : :2:0: unexpected end of input
>   1: paste('','',bgroup('(', paste('','',frac(paste('M'), paste('','L')),'',phantom() == phantom(),'0','.','08','') )
>      ^

Comment: And if you do not need a closing parenthesis, use `\right.` (with a dot). This signals TeX the closing of the `\left(`, but the delimiter is invisible.

Comment: @AlainMerigot please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Tex expects that for each `\left` you also write a `\right`. This is neccessary to calculate the height of the brackets, as e.g. `\left(0.08 \right) = \frac{M}{L}` produces brackets of a different height than `\left(0.08 = \frac{M}{L}\right)`.

You example works with

```
TeX("$(\\left(\\frac{M}{L} = 0.08\\right)$")
```

Note that we have to add extra backslashes to the TeX code to make it work in `R`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The following code worked: `TeX("$(\\left(\\frac{M}{L} = 0.08\\right)$")`

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Right now it is not understandable without the comments.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24728091)

Comment: @silverFoxA the problem is that no-one answered with a true answer, but only left a comment below the question.